# не могу открыть в браузере Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Установил Apache Nifi на сервер Ubuntu 20.4 который стоит на Виртуальной машине на ПК.
Вот результат команды sudo ./nifi.sh status
**2021-10-26 12:30:48,894 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Apache NiFi is currently running, listening to Bootstrap on port 46501, PID=2624**
В браузере вводил **http://127.0.0.1:8080; http://127.0.0.1:8443/ и http://localhost:8080/** - один результат "**Не удается открыть эту страницу**".
Где то прочитал, что нужно открыть порты, открыл(8080; 8443):
**firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload**
Ни чего не помогает...
Есть идеи?

Comment: браузер открываете на виртуальной машине?

Comment: нет на ПК на которой установлена МВ @Alexandr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как вы думаете, откуда ваша система должна понять, что при обращении на **http://localhost:8080/** она должна перенаправлять запрос на виртуальную машину? Само слово **localhost ("local" + "host")** ни о чем не говорит? А если у вас двадцать виртуальных машин запущено на локальной, и, если на каждой из этих двадцати запущены свои веб-серверы, то откуда ей знать, на какую из них обращаться, когда в строке браузера вы набираете **http://localhost:8080/**?

Вместо **http://localhost:8080/** и **http://127.0.0.1:8080** на локальной машине вы должны использовать IP адрес виртуальной машины, чтобы ваша локальная система могла бы "обратиться" по нужному адресу. Ну, само собой, сервер, запущенный на виртуальной, должен быть сконфигурирован так, чтобы слушать не только на "своем" **localhost**, но это уже другая тема.

Т.е. как-то так: **http://10.10.10.5:8080/**, где **10.10.10.5** это IP вашей виртуальной машины.

UPD: использовать надо https, а не http, т.е. **https://ip:8443/nifi**

Comment: у меня настроено ssh подключение через Сетевой мост.
Подскажите, что бы получить ip ВМ в терминале запущенного на этой ВМ Ubuntu я пишу "ifconfig" и получаю 2 ip адреса(127.0.0.1 и адрес ВМ), так?

Comment: @Александр, 127.0.0.1 в списке адресов будет у любого хоста, имеющего хоть один сетевой интерфейс. Обращаясь по такому адресу, хост всегда будет "смотреть" на себя, так это localhost. Т.е. обращение на 127.0.0.1 с самого же себя будет всегда обращаться к самому себе.

В вашем случае вам надо использовать "другой" IP адрес, который вам выводит команда ifconfig (или ip a) - т.е. тот IP адрес, который виден вашему ПК (до которого настроена маршрутизация, которая у вас, само собой, присутствует уже, так вы, как уже сказали, что подключаетесь по ssh - так вот, используйте этот самый IP).

Comment: я тк тоже пробывал, при этом указывал разные порты (8443; 8080), все равно нет соединения. при этом nifi запущен, проверял 'service nifi status'

Comment: @Александр, тогда запустите http://localhost:8080/  или http://localhost:8443/ на виртуальной машине, в зависимости от того, какой порт у вас настроен (настроен ли? Может там порт 80? 8090? 3000? - мы же не знаем). Если работает на виртуальной локально для нее, значит, у вас на виртуальной порт не открыт наружу. Если не работает даже там, то либо порт не тот, либо сервер не поднят.

Смотрите порт командой netstat -an | grep 8080

Comment: @Александр

Надеюсь, вы https, а не http.

Now that NiFi has been started, we can bring up the User Interface (UI) in order to create and monitor our dataflow. 


To get started, open a web browser and navigate to 


_https://localhost:8443/nifi

The port can be changed by editing the nifi.properties file in the NiFi conf directory, but the default port is 8443.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!
я вводил http. Сейчас попробовал с https так же не подключается.
Редактировал файл nifi.properties указывал ip ВМ и порт - все равно не смог достучаться.
И я сдался, установил на Винду дистрибутив из архива версия: 1.0.0. - работает! Пробывал 14 и 13 версии устанавливать, не работаю.

Comment: точнее не 13 и 14 версии а 1.13 и 1.14